# StringCollection.Count incrementing unexpectedly

Tags: c#

I'm working on a method that will trim each element in a `StringCollection` to remove all the excess in each element that I don't need. What is strange is when I was trying to get this method working (it does now) I noticed when introducing a breakpoint in the code that the `groupsToClean.Count` gets incremented with each iteration of the `for` loop and I can't see why.

Does anyone know why?

```
private StringCollection CleanUpGroups(StringCollection groupsToClean)
{
    StringCollection cleanedGroups = groupsToClean;

    for (int i = 0; i < groupsToClean.Count; i++)
    {
        if (groupsToClean[i].IndexOf(",") != -1)
        {
            string temp = groupsToClean[i].Substring(3, (groupsToClean[i].IndexOf(",") - 3));
            cleanedGroups.Add(temp);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return cleanedGroups;
}
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [StringCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) is a reference type. Your `cleanedGroups` and `groupsToClean` are the same object, so you add "cleaned" items to the collection from which you originally got them.

To solve this problem just create new `cleanedGroups` at the beginning of your method:

```
private StringCollection CleanUpGroups(StringCollection groupsToClean)
{
    var cleanedGroups = new StringCollection();
```

Comment: Annnnd now I feel dumb. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

This line creates two references to the same collection:

```
StringCollection cleanedGroups = groupsToClean;
```

So when you call this, you're actually adding to the `groupsToClean` collection too:

```
cleanedGroups.Add(temp);  // adds to groupsToClean too
```

You'll need to replace the original occurrence with your modified one, or create a new collection.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I wish I could mark more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

`StringCollection` is a reference type. `cleanedGroups` is not a copy of `groupsToClean` -- it's the same instance.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I wish I could mark more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `StringCollection` to an Array to clone it

look at the MS reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx